# How to override Magento model file that extends PHP class

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, overrides, model

I want to override a model file of another extension into my extension in order to develop the compatibility between the two extensions

The class I want to override is `class Customweb_PostFinanceCw_Model_OrderContext extends Customweb_Payment_Authorization_OrderContext_AbstractDeprecated implements Customweb_Payment_Authorization_IOrderContext` this class also extends another class of PHP

Please help me in extending this file.

Comment: I also need help in this

Comment: The same way as you would rewrite any other model. What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Below a simple example of how to override a model from one module within another module.

Please take a look at the file `app/code/local/Customweb/PostFinanceCw/etc/config.xml` for the correct use of the modulename namespace (which I can't read from your question, I used `customweb_postfinancecw` for now).

You'd have to have a piece of XML like this in your module's `config.xml` (I named it `MyCompany_MyModule`, please replace it with your own)

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
            <customweb_postfinancecw>
                <rewrite>
                    <ordercontext>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_OrderContext</ordercontext>
                </rewrite>
            </customweb_postfinancecw>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then, in `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Model/`, create a file `OrderContext.php` like this

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_OrderContext extends Customweb_PostFinanceCw_Model_OrderContext
{

    /* Override methods now */

}
```

You should name the methods exactly the same as in the original `Customweb_PostFinanceCw_Model_OrderContext` class to override it's functionality. Also keep in mind to keep the same visibility (public, protected or private).

Comment: @PratikBhatt, above is how you could override the model. I can't understand from your question what further problems you exactly run into (extending a PHP class?). Please update your question if you have any other problems regarding overriding this model.

Comment: @70Chem I tried this  but this does not call my new model and just calls the previous one.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt you could trace back the calls to the methods of the `Customweb_PostFinanceCw_Model_OrderContext` class and see how it is called. Sometimes I see extensions where they instantiate the class directly: `$instance = new Customweb_PostFinanceCw_Model_OrderContext()` instead of `Mage::getModel(...)`. So then overriding will never work...